# Error 1146 table doesn't exist and I cannot delete the table

Tags: magento2, database, error

In phpmyadmin there's a list of tables in my database which show up on the left hand side but they don't all show up on the right hand side.

When I click spme of these tables on the left hand side I get

```
"error 1146 table doesn't exist"
```

I cannot delete the table as it doesn't show up in the right hand side for me to delete it.

Please help me get the tables back or delete it?

Comment: Please refer below link if it can help you : https://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/security-admin/resolving-mysql-error-1146-table-doesnt-exist-when-doing-backup/

Answer (score 0):

Check with your MySQL directory `/var/lib/mysql` filename here with same database name, its corrupted. please delete file and re-import database.

Comment: please go thorough this i  have getting  issue "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279654/magento2-3-0-on-checkout-page-first-time-loader-loading-non-stop-after-refresh"

Comment: if you have idea reply me