# Magento2.3.0: On checkout page first time loader loading non stop after refresh its working on it loader hide

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.0, loader

When I go to checkout page there loader loading non stop loading this issue comes on chrome browser only normal and private browser.

I have to check it log but not getting any error related to js.